# All words in text with more than 1 uppercase characters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to select all words in text with more than 1 uppercase characters?
I managed to select a certain word with this line:

`(?<![a-z])word(?![a-z])`

But I'm not sure how to select words like `SElect, SeLeCt, SelecT, seleCT, selEcT`.

Comment: Are you matching against a specific word with variable casing or any string of characters containing at least an uppercase letter? If it's the latter, would something like this work? `^([a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*)$`

Comment: I think you need `/(?<![A-Za-z])(?:[a-z]*[A-Z]){2}[A-Za-z]*(?![A-Za-z])/g`, that is, a letter word between non-letter symbols with at least two uppercase letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. This is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a pattern to assert what is at the right is the "word" and match 2 uppercase characters surrounded by optional upper and lowercase characters

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(?![a-zA-Z])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` Assert not a-zA-Z at the left
- `[a-z]*[A-Z]` Match optional chars a-z followed by A-Z to match the first uppercase char
- `[a-z]*[A-Z]` Match again optional chars a-z followed by A-Z to match the second uppercase char
- `[a-zA-Z]*` Match optional chars a-zA-Z
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` Assert not a-zA-Z at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7LdTNE/1)

Comment: @Neret All words like this? `(?<![a-z])[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?![a-z])` https://regex101.com/r/bVIsd7/1

Comment: Yes, All words like this. But the boundaries should be `[a-zA-Z]`, not `\b`.

Comment: @Neret `(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?![a-zA-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/sNdVBg/1

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is the answer. Could you explain a bit how it works?

Comment: Is it possible to assert at least one lowercase letter in the selection?

Comment: You are genius! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /([a-z]*[A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]*){2,}\b/g
const str = "SEEEEect, SeLeCt, SelecT, seleCT, selEcT select, seleCT, selEcT select, donselect"

const match = str.match(regex)
console.log(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me also suggest a fully Unicode regex:

```js
/(?<!\p{L})(?:\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}){2}\p{L}*(?!\p{L})/gu
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/4s9KO6/1).

**Explanation**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}                  any Unicode letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Ll}*                 any lowercase Unicode letter (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Lu}                   any uppercase Unicode letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{L}*                   any Unicode letter (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}                   any Unicode letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
const regex = /(?<!\p{L})(?:\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}){2}\p{L}*(?!\p{L})/gu;
const string = "SEEEEect, SeLeCt, SelecT, seleCT, selEcT select, seleCT, selEcT select, donselect";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```